# Force-Mount windows hibernated partition in Read/Write mode

Tags: linux-mint, mount, windows

I have a dual boot system with an `NTFS partition (C:)` dedicated to the `windows 8 OS files`, an `EXT4 partition` dedicated to `Linux Mint 17`.

There is also another `NTFS partition (E:)` which I would like to use for some files **shared between the two OS's**.

The problem is that whenever I **hibernate** Windows 8 it sets the `hibernation flag` on both `C:` and `E:` making it impossible to write into the shared partition from Linux.

Is there any way to force Linux Mint to mount the partiton as R/W or to prevent windows 8 from setting this flag on the shared partition? I know that an obvious solution would be to just normally shutdown windows 8 (with fast boot disabled) but I really need to have it hibernated.

Comment: Since Windows is the culprit here, I'm afraid U&L does not really fit for your question (unless someone knows a way to take the partition from Windows' hands). Nevertheless, [here's a related answer on AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/145904/175072).

Answer (score 14):

ntfs-3g has an option that will force delete the hibernation file and force a rw mount:

```bash
mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sdXX /media/windows
```

If it's still giving you errors, try running `ntfsfix` as **root** (e.g. with `sudo`) to fix errors in the NTFS file system:

```bash
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXX
```

From ntfs-3g(8):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> mount -t ntfs-3g [-o option[,...]]  volume mount_point
>
> **OPTIONS**
>
> **remove_hiberfile**
>
> Unlike in case of read-only mount, the read-write mount is denied if the NTFS volume is hibernated. One needs either to resume Windows and shutdown it properly, or use this option which will remove  the  Windows  hibernation  file. Please note, this means that the saved Windows session will be completely lost. Use this option under your own responsibility.

Comment: I have a windows  partition corrupted by some images files but can't mount it because has a hibernate state, I'ĺl try this later, thanks

Comment: It has no effect for me, still refuses to mount with "The disk contains an unclean file system. Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount". Only running the `ntfsfix` from the other answer worked.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Added `ntfsfix` solution as a suggestion under my original answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

If you want to keep hibernation and also be able to access *all* hibernate flagged partitions (such C:) by Windows OS on Mint 17, then you will lose the hibernate status on Windows. If you want to access just another partition than C: (which is your Windows partition), you can do so by executing:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY
```

...where you must change `XY` depending on where your partition is mounted. For example it can be mounted on `/dev/sda2`. You can use `gparted` to find this location:

[image: Screenshot of Gparted]

(Reminder: you will lose the hibernation status on Windows if you force mount the partition where you installed Windows(C:))

Answer (score 0):

Just unmount the shared NTFS partition.
Create a batch file and place it in `/local disk c/windows` .

Then you can simply enter the name of batch file in run to unmount it.
You can create a similar batch file to mount it back and you can do the same to mount it from run.

Before you shut down, enter the unmounting batch file name.
After turn on, enter the mounting batch file name.
All in run, so easy and handy.

To unmount:

```
@echo off
set drive=E (replace with yours)
mountvol %drive% /p
exit
```

Save this as `volunmount.cmd` .

To mount:

```
@echo off
set drive=E (replace it with yours)
set volume=\\?\Volume{your partion ID,Google how to find}\
:start
mountvol %drive%: %volume%
exit
```

Save it as `volmount.cmd`.

In run after typing, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd> to run as admin.

Comment: @echo off, set drive=E , mountvol %drive% /p, exit - all in seperate lines and also applicable for second one.